# error codes on eclipse ld:symbols not found for architecture make:***Error 1

Tags: c

I have a simple project on eclipse but I am getting error code when I build but I don't know what to do. Here are my error codes

`Building target: arrayrearrange
Invoking: MacOS X C Linker
gcc  -o "arrayrearrange"  ./arrayrearrange.o

Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_main", referenced from:
     implicit entry/start for main executable
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [arrayrearrange] Error 1`

Edit: Here is the code

```
#include <stdio.h>
void rearrange(int *a1, int n,  int *a2);
int main(){
    int N, i;
    printf("Enter the length of the array:");
    scanf("%d", &N);
    int array1[N], array2[N];
    printf("Enter the elements of the array:");
    for(i = 0; i<N; i++){
        scanf("%d", &array1[i]);
    }
    rearrange(array1, N, array2);
    printf("Output: ");
    for(i = 0; i<N; i++){
        printf("%d", array2[i]);
        }
}
void rearrange(int *a1, int n,  int *a2){
    int *i, *j=a2;
    for(i = a1; i<a1+n; i++){
        if((i-a1) % 2 == 0 || i==0){
            *(j + (n/2))++ = *i;
        }
        else if((i-a1) % 2 != 0){
            *j++ = *i;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that shows the problem is needed. Did you try a "Hello World" progam?

Comment: This code does not even compile. Have you tried compiling it with just `gcc arrayrearrange.c`?

Answer (score 0):

You are building an executable for your MacOS X platform using a pre-compiled object file `arrayrearrange.o`.

Every C program must define a `main()` function somewhere, in order to be run.

So either `arrayrearrange.c` doesn't contain any `main()` function, or `arrayrearrange.o` was compiled on another machine, with a different architecture, and your linker (`ld`) complains because it can't find a compatible compiled code. In that latter case, just recompile `arrayrearrange.c`.